# How to preview the order confirmation page

Tags: php, magento

Working on skinning the order confirmation page. Is there a way I can view this without having to place an order each time?

Comment: Done quite a bit, heavy overhaul of layout xml and phtml files. Just at the tweaking CSS stage.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure there is , comment out the session clearing check in `Mage_Checkout_OnepageController` in `successAction` method.

The part that ruins the day for you is `$session->clear();` so comment it out while testing and enable after you are finished

Comment: I had to also comment out the 2 redirects and returns to stop it redirecting to the cart in that method.